# Send email in c# with out showing sender

Tags: c#

Am trying to send mail from one distribution list to another distribution list using my mail id and password and it succeed.  But we see in the show original tab (located at the top right near the reply arrow) it shows the sender my mail id.  I need to show the sender as sender distribution list instead of showing my mail id.

Can any one help me to solve this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
namespace SendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //SENDING MAIL
            Console.WriteLine("*****SENDING MAIL*****");
                 try
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("DL: " + rID);

                     string sID = "DL1@xxxxxx.com>";
          string rID="DL2@xxxxxx.com>";
                     string senderID = "xxxx@xxxxxx.com";
                     string senderPassword = "xxxxxxxx";
                     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                     mail.To.Add(rID);
                     mail.From = new MailAddress(sID);
                     mail.Subject = "Testing";
                     mail.Body = "Hi ";                                                                       
          mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(sID);
                     mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
                     SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                     smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                     smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword);
                     smtp.Port = 587;
                     smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                     Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
                     smtp.Send(mail);
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.Write("ERROR:" + ex.Message);
                     Console.ReadLine();
                 }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code here you are using to send email, don't forget to hide your credentials.

Comment: At least try to post what you have done so far.. so that others can help.

Comment: @TFrost now plz see the code

Comment: It might be possible that for security concerns Googles mail servers always show the "correct" sender mail. If they wouldn't they were open to be used as spam relays. ( I post this as a comment as I cannot state this as a fact for Google, but I know of other servers that they act like this )

Comment: Im not sure you can hide your email. However you could use a Display Name to show instead of the name of your mail account: MailAddress mad = new MailAddress(fromMailAddress, fromDisplayName);

Comment: @Zukki ya we do that too. But our main problem is the receiver DL is opened in outlook means while they click reply button it shows my mail id not the sender DL.

Comment: Would creating an email account for theses kind of message be appropriate ?

Comment: I would use the reply-to address then if you can't override the sender.